# javascript prototyping, what am i doing wrong here

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/johnm01/c5k0yevm/

im trying to understand prototyping again but not sure what im doing wrong here, why is undefined output when the method screamName is called?

```
function Person1(name, age, sex) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.sex = sex;
  this.sayName = function sayMyName() {
  alert(this.name + this.age + this.sex);
}


};

var p1 = new Person1("tim", 56, "male");
p1.sayName();

Person1.prototype.screamName = function screamName(name) {
  this.name = name;
  alert(this.name);
};
p1.screamName();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `screamName` function expects a `name` argument which you're not supplying, and subsequently are assigning to `this.name`. Thus, it is `undefined`. I believe you intended to write this:

```
Person1.prototype.screamName = function screamName() {
  alert(this.name);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like you've defined your method to take in a parameter of "name", but you haven't actually passed any parameter into the method when you call it. I also think that you need to create a new Person1 object in order to have a Person1 object with the screamname method.

```
function Person1(name, age, sex) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.sex = sex;
  this.sayName = function sayMyName() {
      alert(this.name + this.age + this.sex);
  }
}

var p1 = new Person1("tim", 56, "male");
p1.sayName();

Person1.prototype.screamName = function screamName() {
  alert(this.name);
};

var p2 = new Person1("bob", 22, "male");
p2.screamName();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/johnm01/c5k0yevm/